# What format should uploaded videos be converted to using FFMpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, mp4, wmv

I want to use FFMpeg to process short, uploaded videos for storage on a linux server.

These videos will be played back using the html5 version of Flowplayer.  I don't care about supporting FLV.

I also don't care if the conversion introduces artifacts into the videos, so long as they are understandable.  I do care about keeping filesize to a (reasonable) minimum.

What format should I use FFMpeg to convert the videos to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://flowplayer.org/docs/#video-formats:

> Your best bet for reliable HTML5 video is to provide MP4 and WEBM
>   variants for each of your videos.

in short : mp4 for more browsers support if you need to choose one format only